# Meaning of the phrasal verb "hold over" in context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

I have stumpled upon it in this [video](https://youtu.be/2GaMxk08ZLM). It is at 37 seconds

> Here are three sunken lands that might **hold** you **over** until the fish people turn up.

I have looked it up in a few dictionaries, but I still cannot make head nor tail of what it means in the sentence.

Comment: I see nothing confusing about the standard dictionary definition of the term. What is it about it that doesn't make sense?

Comment: @JasonBassford Can you cite a dictionary definition that fits in this sentence? I can't find one in the OED, nor in the top few dictionary website results. Note that neither "to keep for future consideration or action; postpone" nor "to remain in possession or beyond the regular term" nor "to remain beyond the arranged period" (the three OED def'ns) can possibly work.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I find nothing at all wrong with the normal use of *postpone* or *defer* as [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hold%20over#h2). A snack that *holds you over* until dinner delays hunger until such time as it can be properly addressed (by a full meal). *Tide over* does the same thing, but it's simply synonymous. There's nothing wrong with *hold over*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Intuition is all well and good, but it gets fuzzy in just such cases as these where there are similar expressions (hold sthg, tide sb over). And when two native speakers' intuitions disagree, intuition isn't much help. That's why I asked if you could find this sense in a dictionary. "Postpone hunger" isn't the same as "postpone you".

Comment: @LukeSawczak Exactly the same thing could be said of *tide you*. (At least *hold* has some applicability with the word's normal meaning; *tide* makes little sense on its own.) You're simply replacing one phrase with another and saying that the other is correct because you like it more. Both *do* have dictionary definitions, and both do say roughly the same thing, There is no objective reason to pick one over the other.

Comment: @JasonBassford Whereas tide over has an applicable dictionary definition and hold over doesn't, the test I propose does actually favour the one over the other

Comment: @LukeSawczak On the contrary, I find them both just as applicable. The way I look at it, it was like answering the question *What is the meaning of "leap" in this context?* with the answer *"Jump" is a better word, and here is what it means.*

Comment: @JasonBassford OK, well, just slot the dictionary definitions for hold over into the sentence and you'll see that they're not interchangeable like jump and leap. None of them could take "you" as the object. You hold something over for later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there's a regional variation I haven't found in a dictionary yet, the speaker is slightly mixing their phrasal verbs. They mean ***tide* over**.

To [tide someone over](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tide%20over) is to temporarily satisfy or support them, because something better is coming soon.

> – Mom, I'm hungry. Can we have supper *now*?
>
> – No, it's only 4. You can have a granola bar or a yogurt to tide you over till supper.

It's easy to see how a person might mix up these two expressions, since "hold over" has some overlap in the idea of "delay till later". But it doesn't quite mean the same thing (at least in my North American English).

Comment: Incidentally, "tide over" would have been a better image for the video, too :)